# How can I get the function return

Tags: javascript

How can I return the name of the city to show on html page?

My function

```
function getCity(latitude, longitude){

var geocoder;
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(); 
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
geocoder.geocode(
    {'latLng': latlng}, 
    function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                if (results[0]) {
                    var add= results[0].formatted_address ;
                    var  value=add.split(",");

                    count=value.length;
                    country=value[count-1];
                    state=value[count-2];
                    city=value[count-3];
                    alert("city name is: " + city);
                    return city;
                }
        }

    }
);
```

The alert is working fine.

In HTML I called this function like that:

```
 <script> getCity("<%= map.latitude %>","<%= map.longitude %>")</script>
```

Tks in advance.

Comment: `geocode` is an asynchronous call.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
<script> document.write(getCity("<%= map.latitude %>","<%= map.longitude %>"))</script>
```

It will write into the document what your Javascript function returns.

Comment: It is returning "undefined"

Comment: `document.write` displays the value returned by the call to `getCity`. If it displays null, then there is something wrong in the function code. You need to debug to find out where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Create a DIV in your HTML, like this:

```
<div id="cityName"></div>
```

And in the javascript, replace the "alert" with this code:

```
document.getElementById("cityName").innerHTML(city);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the alert works fine that means returned value is true.
Then u can just call the function that returns the city name anywhere in the document body.
Alternatively since the function only returns a string,  u just need to assign it to a new variable and add more information to the returned function city string.

Like**function city ()
    Return  a city name value.

**then**
var cityname = city() + 'more information';

**

Comment: Hope it helps. Just apply it in reference to your original function code.